# Validate multiple start and date date fields with Angular 7 or later

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material

I have multiple start and end date input fields. I could not find a way to validate them. I tried to validate them but could not get relevant output.

This is stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhbuqn-wpbwjw

I have several goals here:

1) Need to set default dates which I have mentioned in the ts file. There 
   is commented code which I have tried to set default values.

2) The error message does not display if the end date is greater than the start date. You can see a red border is being applied but message does not display.

3) I could not set the values for the second set of start and end date input fields.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part, to set the date, try this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      users: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            startDate: [this.startDate],
            endDate: [this.endDate]
          },
          { validator: this.checkDates }
        )
      ])
    });
  }
```

For the 2nd part, try this:
In this way you have to manually touch the input,or you can try with `this.myForm.markAllAsTouched();`

```
<mat-error              *ngIf="myForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['endDate'].touched && myForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].invalid">
                End date cannot be earlier than start date
</mat-error>
```

or

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['endDate'].value != null && myForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].invalid ">
                End date cannot be earlier than start date
</mat-error>
```